# Hint in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

I tried to show a hint in the EditText of my form, but i can't see that hint that i have set in the XML Layout while my application gets deployed, but i can able see the hint in eclipse designer view, but while getting deployed the same hint suppose to appear is missing, i tried with all the possible ways still i could not get the hint in the EditText... This is one of the Edit Text layout that i have used..

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/SetTimerSec_EditText01"
    android:layout_width="60sp" 
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:layout_x="220sp" 
    android:layout_y="170sp"
    android:hint="0"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:textColorHint="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

[link text][1]

Can anybody Help me..Please

Thanks in advance

[1]: [[http://imgur.com/PzomF.jpg](https://imgur.com/PzomF.jpg)](https://imgur.com/PzomF.jpg)
[ScreenShot of Designer View with hint displayed][1]

Comment: what is your `EditText`'s `layout_width` value?

Comment: Hi praveen, this is the Width and Height of My EditText 
android:layout_width="60sp" android:layout_height="40sp"

Comment: can you post XML source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like a SDK bug, or at least related to one.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7252

The hint shows up if you remove the following:
android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 4):

add `android:ellipsize="start"` and your hint will show up and be centered!

Comment: sorry for the noob question but why does my answer say community wiki instead of the normal thing with my reputation etc?