# android EditText hint does not appear

Tags: android, android-edittext

It seems to be the most weird thing that I've ever come across.

Here is a layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText        
    android:id="@+id/GuessAppEditText"
    android:lines="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"        
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:hint="@string/Hint" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `hint` of `EditText` is not shown.

If I remove either `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` or `android:inputType="textCapWords"`, hint becomes visible.

I have absolutely no idea what has `gravity` and `textCapWords` to do with `hint`. Is it another Android bug or am I doing something wrong? In the former case, what would be a workaround? I want my text to be center-aligned and capitalized and hint to be shown. Or I want too much from poor Android?

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/a/3643494/1134705

Comment: Have you tried to remove the hint and set it programmatically, to see if that is a workaround?

Comment: android:gravity="center_horizontal" creates the problem...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just add a single line and it will work, i.e `android:ellipsize="start"`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/GuessAppEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:lines="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Likely that the original accept answer is no longer valid for latest android version, by setting up the hint color will make the hint display:

```
android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
```

Hope this helps others, tested with Android 5+

Answer (score 1):

it's 2021 and this still seems to be an issue, so for anyone running trying to use an EditText and not seeing the hint in the designer you can add `tools:background="@android:color/transparent"` or assign any color to the background and the hint will appear.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug, as noted [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7252). Seems like a few people in that thread have posted work around's or resolutions you could try. Have you tried to remove the hint and set it programmatically, to see if that is a workaround?

Declare this before `onCreate()`

```java
EditText guessAppEt;
```

And this in `onCreate()`

```java
guessAppEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.GuessAppEditText);
guessAppEt.setHint("Your hint here");
```